# Wildfly migration tool from 8.2.0 to latest

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

i saw in https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration/releases that we can migrate wildfly  WildFly 8.2 to WildFly 17.0 in last release 1.7.0 but when i try i had this error 
'''

```
Server migration starting...
 ERROR Migration failed: org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigrationFailureException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFCMTOOL000004: Server name = WildFly
, version = 8.2.0.Final does not support migration from server name = WildFly Full, version = 16.0.0.Final.
        at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:174) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.7.0.Final.jar:1.7.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigration.run(ServerMigration.java:160) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.7.0.Final.jar:1.7.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.migration.cli.CommandLineServerMigration.main(CommandLineServerMigration.java:131) [jboss-server-migration-cli-1.7.0.Final.jar:1.7.0.Fi
nal]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFCMTOOL000004: Server name = WildFly, version = 8.2.0.Final does not support migration from server name = Wi
ldFly Full, version = 16.0.0.Final.
        at org.jboss.migration.core.AbstractServer.migrate(AbstractServer.java:63) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.7.0.Final.jar:1.7.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigration$1.run(ServerMigration.java:153) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.7.0.Final.jar:1.7.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:169) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.7.0.Final.jar:1.7.0.Final]
        ... 2 more
```

My question can i migrate from 8 to 16 directly ?

Comment: What version are you really migrating to?  Your title says "latest" (which is 19 beta or 18.0.1 released) but your question says both 17 and 16.  Nothing in 1.7.0.Final of that tool indicates that Wildfly 16 is supported so if it's really 16 you need to use 1.6.0.Final that indicates support for Wildfly 16.  What makes you think you need a tool - have you tried to run your code as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logging it looks like you swapped the source and target server parameters, but the tool's 1.7 release only supports migrations to WildFly 17 or 18 anyway, to migrate to WildFly 16 you should use https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration/releases/tag/1.6.0.Final

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment. Although one would think, that the newest version could also migrate as the older versions can. But that is not the case here.
In order to update v16 to v22 I needed the 1.10.0.Final version of the migration tool.

Answer (score 0):

About Jboss (or) Wildfly Application Server Migration, when I was migrating jboss/wildfly with wildfly-server-migration, same error happened.

I was running the jboss migration tool with a command similar to:

```
"./jboss-server-migration.sh -n --source /opt/wildfly-x.x.x.Final/ --target /opt/wildfly-x.x.x.Final" .
```

(See documentation at https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration).

After a few tries, I found that I had downloaded the wrong TARGET distribution from https://www.wildfly.org/downloads/.

When I used "Jakarta EE 8 Full & Web Distribution" into directory of "--target" argument, the command was executed successfully.